# htaccess rewrite rule to a specific PHP page doesn't work

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, apache2, rewritecond

I have the following code in my `.htaccess` file, placed in the root of my **Ubuntu 22.04** instance:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

My goal is to use:

`example.com/profile/johndoe`

to get the following output URL:

`example.com/profile.php?user=johndoe`

but it doesn't work :(

`mod_rewrite` is on

My `apache2.conf` looks like this:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting your `.htaccess` file in `/var/www/html/`. Your issue is probably permission related. Check your logs in `/var/log/apache2/access.log` and `/var/log/apache2/error.log` for more details.

Also, do not allow access to the root filesystem, it's a security issue. So change

```httpd
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks, my htaccess file is already in var/www/html/, I’ll check access.log to see if there’s anything wrong, anyway if I perform a rewrite rule on the index.php, it works, it just doesn’t get another php file with a single?parameter :(